# Whats wrong with my reasoning here

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways of giving $3n$ different toys to Maddy,Jimmy and Tommy so that Maddy and Jimmy together get $2n$ toys.

My attemp and flawed reasoning:

The number of ways of choosing $2n$ toys out of $3n$ toys is $C(3n,2n)$ and the number of ways of distributing $2n$ different toys among $2$ children is $2n+1$, hence $(2n+1)C(3n,2n)$ is the answer. But my book says it should be $C(3n,n)2^{2n}$. Obviously I got it wrong. Whats wrong with my solution?

Comment: The toys are intended to be distinguishable from each other, as you have realized in the the C(3n,2n) computation. But in distributing 2n toys to 2 children, you have made the toys indistinguishable from each other by saying there are 2n+1 ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the $2n$ toys, each can be given either to Maddy, or else to the Jimmy. Two choices are available (and hence, there are 2 ways of distributing) for every toy: That gives us $$\underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdots \cdot 2}_{2n \text{ toys }} = 2^{2n}$$ ways to distribute $2n$ toys to Maddy and Jimmy.

Note also that $$C(3n,n) = \frac{(3n)!}{n!(2n)!} = C(3n, 2n)$$

Comment: Nice explanation, I get it.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to distribute $m$ toys to 2 children is $2^m$; imagine that you make a sequence of the $m$ toys, then you can say which child the toy goes to by putting a 0 or 1.  There are clearly $2^m$ possible sequences of 0's and 1's.

With $m=2n$, you have $2^{2n}$.

As far as $C(3n,n)$ goes, notice that it is the same as $C(3n,2n)$ since $n+2n=3n$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to distribute $2n$ different toys among $2$ children is $2^{2n}$ because each toy has two choices of which child to go to and each toy is distinct; not $2n+1$ as you claim (it would be $2n+1$ if the toys were not distinct).